# Emoji appearing as unknown/special characters on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts, discord.js

I registered Roboto Bold and used it on a text on my canvas but the emoji character is showing as square/special/unknown character. It's fine on local client, but when deployed on **Heroku** the issue happens. I'm doing this on Discord. The text is supposed to be a channel name that has an emoji. I tried using a different font like Arial but it also cannot output emojis.

I tried using NotoColorEmoji Regular font. It can output the emoji as expected but it doesn't seem to output text because they appear as square characters.

What's the fix for this? Is there a font that can read both text and emoji? Here's a discussion that is about this: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/760

```
Canvas.GlobalFonts.registerFromPath("./font/Roboto-Bold.ttf", "Roboto Bold");

context.font = "22px Roboto Bold";
context.textAlign = 'left';
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillText(` channel`, 650, 292);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `Noto Color Emoji` as fallback fonts.

```js
context.font = '22px "Roboto Bold", "Noto Color Emoji"';
// --snip--
context.fillText(` channel`, 650, 292);
```